# How to change the currentText of repeated ComboBox in QML?

Tags: javascript, qml

As I understand it, it is not possible to directly change the property `currentText` of a QML `ComboBox`. Instead, one needs to access it via `currentIndex`. However, I cannot seem to get it either. The JS code I need to update the text of a `ComboBox` with is the following:

```
    function fillCombosFromHistory (s, rep1, rep2, replength) {
      let u = s.replace(/\s+/g,'').split('&');
      let v = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < u.length; i++) {
        v.push({
          key: u[i].split('=')[0],
          value: u[i].split('=')[1]
        })
      }
      for (let j = 0; j < v.length; j++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < replength; k++) {
          if (v[j].key === rep1.itemAt(k).text) {
            rep2.itemAt(k).model.currentIndex.text = v[j].value;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Here I pass the ids of two repeaters `rep1` and `rep2`, where `rep1` repeats `Text` (as a label) and `rep2` repeats `ComboBox`. They are forcefully of the same length, so only one `replength`.

PS. I currently get the error `TypeError: Value is undefined and could not be converted to an object`.

Comment: Please create an MRE

Comment: Check to make sure that each element of `v` has an appropriate value property.

Comment: @James I debugged by logging and everything is there. Both keys and values are strings as expected.

Answer (score 1):

So, I solved the problem. Apparently I was just confused about the properties of `ComboBox`. I changed the line

```
rep2.itemAt(k).model.currentIndex.text = v[j].value;
```

to

```
rep2.itemAt(k).editText = v[j].value;
```

and then some logic in other functions to accomodate the change and now everything works. Thanks anyway for the helpful hints!